# deleting a blob from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, image, blob

1) What is the best way to store many images in a MySQL database?

2) how the heck do you delete a blob in a MySQL DB after uploading one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**For Storing Images :**

Personally I suggest you have an image folder, and simply store the image paths in the DB. That way all you do is retrieve a path and pass it to your image container, whatever it may be.

Don't store images in a database.  Maintenance of images becomes exceedingly complex, and the size of the db tends to be unnecessarily large.

You also require extra code to to get back the image data, and display it back to the viewer.

Comment: where would the image folder reside @teez?

Comment: anywhere, you wish on your hosting account. you can give path in script where to upload files.

Comment: such as in my htdocs folder? I'll ask another question with this design in mind...